# position style series of radio buttons vertically

Tags: css, radio-button

I have the following html.

```
<td>
    <div id="form_comparison" class="field radio_field">
        <input type="radio" id="form_comparison_0" name="form[comparison]" value="1"/>
        <label for="form_comparison_0">Increased</label>
        <input type="radio" id="form_comparison_1" name="form[comparison]" value="2" />
        <label for="form_comparison_1">About the same</label>
        <input type="radio" id="form_comparison_2" name="form[comparison]" value="3" />
        <label for="form_comparison_2">Decreased</label>
    </div>
</td>
```

Using css, how can I position radio buttons vertically, so that labels are displayed just after their respective radio buttons in the same line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/tm3Qn/)**</kbd>

Float your `input` and `label`, and for second row, `clear` the `float` to make a new row:

```
#form_comparison input {
    float: left;
}

#form_comparison label {
    float: left;
}

#form_comparison label + input {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you've wrapped this inside a `td` element, if you are designing a form layout, than ignore tables and use `div` for designing your form. Coming to your question, you can wrap the labels around `input` tag and use `display: block;` for `label`

```
#form_comparison label {
    display: block;
}
```

Wrap each `input` using `label` like this

```
<label for="form_comparison_0">
    <input type="radio" id="form_comparison_0" name="form[comparison]" value="1"/>
    Increased
</label>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vjgKu/)

---

If you don't have any permissions to change the markup, you can use CSS `content` property with `white-space: pre;` and that will give you the desired output

```
label:after {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vy3Zm/) (No Changes In The Markup)

> Note: Use `#form_comparison label` instead of only `label` as it will
>   select and apply all `label` element in your website where
>   `#form_comparison label` will only select `label` elements inside
>   `#form_comparison`